# -webkit-linear-gradient causes 400 (Bad request) error in Safari

Tags: compass-sass, linear-gradients, safari

I'm using Compass to generate linear gradients but I'm getting a strange error indicating that Safari (Version 5.1.2 [6534.52.7]) is trying to load the vendor prefixed line as if it's a URI.  Weird!

**The Compass code:**
    body {
        @include background-image(linear-gradient(top, #F7F7F7 0%, #FFFFFF 20%, #cccccc 57%, #dddddd 60%, #f1f1f1 80%, #FFFFFF 100%));
    }

**Generated CSS:**

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #f7f7f7), color-stop(20%, #ffffff), color-stop(57%, #cccccc), color-stop(60%, #dddddd), color-stop(80%, #f1f1f1), color-stop(100%, #ffffff));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7 0%, #ffffff 20%, #cccccc 57%, #dddddd 60%, #f1f1f1 80%, #ffffff 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7 0%, #ffffff 20%, #cccccc 57%, #dddddd 60%, #f1f1f1 80%, #ffffff 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7 0%, #ffffff 20%, #cccccc 57%, #dddddd 60%, #f1f1f1 80%, #ffffff 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7 0%, #ffffff 20%, #cccccc 57%, #dddddd 60%, #f1f1f1 80%, #ffffff 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7 0%, #ffffff 20%, #cccccc 57%, #dddddd 60%, #f1f1f1 80%, #ffffff 100%);
```

**Error: -webkit-linear-gradient**

```
-webkit-linear-gradient(top,%20rgb(247,%20247,%20247)%200%,%20rgb(255,%20255,%20255)%2020%,%20rgb(204,%20204,%20204)%2057%,%20rgb(221,%20221,%20221)%2060%,%20rgb(241,%20241,%20241)%2080%,%20rgb(255,%20255,%20255)%20100%)
GET http://localhost:8888/-webkit-linear-gradient(top,%20rgb(247,%20247,%20247)%200%,%20rgb(255,%20255,%20255)%2020%,%20rgb(204,%20204,%20204)%2057%,%20rgb(221,%20221,%20221)%2060%,%20rgb(241,%20241,%20241)%2080%,%20rgb(255,%20255,%20255)%20100%) 400 (Bad Request)
```

**Error: -webkit-gradient()**

```
-webkit-gradient(linear,%2050%%200%,%2050%%20100%,%20from(rgb(247,%20247,%20247)),%20color-stop(0.2,%20rgb(255,%20255,%20255)),%20color-stop(0.57,%20rgb(204,%20204,%20204)),%20color-stop(0.6,%20rgb(221,%20221,%20221)),%20color-stop(0.8,%20rgb(241,%20241,%20241)),%20to(rgb(255,%20255,%20255)))
GET http://localhost:8888/-webkit-gradient(linear,%2050%%200%,%2050%%20100%,%20from(rgb(247,%20247,%20247)),%20color-stop(0.2,%20rgb(255,%20255,%20255)),%20color-stop(0.57,%20rgb(204,%20204,%20204)),%20color-stop(0.6,%20rgb(221,%20221,%20221)),%20color-stop(0.8,%20rgb(241,%20241,%20241)),%20to(rgb(255,%20255,%20255))) 400 (Bad Request)
```

Despite the error, the gradient is rendered correctly.  Also there are numerous other multi-stop linear gradients throughout the page which don't cause the error.  It appears that this is a Safari bug - it occurs only when the gradient is used in the .  Check out some code (see the error live if you're running Safari):

1. [With error (gradient in Body Tag)](http://jsfiddle.net/YxJZU/5/)
2. [No error (same gradient elsewhere)](http://jsfiddle.net/YxJZU/4/)

Any ideas/solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not seeing the error in Safari Version 5.1.3 (7534.53.10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @maxbeatty for checking it out on your version of Safari.  Your post led me to dig in a little further, and to disable all plugins. I found that the culprit was the Safari AdBlock Plugin.  Disabling it made the error go away.